# Is there a function to search a value in a pandas cell list, and return the rows if the value is solitary or the only type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the follow dataframe:

```
df1
ID                    Task           Type
[2456-AA, 5656-BB]    Check AC       [Coolant]
[2456-AA, 2457-AA]    Check Equip1.  [Coolant , Elec]
[2456-AA, 2456-AA]    Check Equip2.  [Coolant , Coolant]
[2456-AA, 2657-AA]    Check Equip3.  [Coolant , Bat2]
```

I'm trying to return an output that would tell me all of the tasks & IDs where 'Coolant' is in the 'Type'. But, only the tasks & IDs where coolant isn't mixed with any other type.

I think my expected output would be a dataframe like this:

```
ID                    Task           Type
[2456-AA, 5656-BB]    Check AC       [Coolant]
[2456-AA, 2456-AA]    Check Equip2.  [Coolant , Coolant]
```

Could somebody have a go at it? Also, could they refer me to the correct reading material in oprder to help me approach a similar problem in the future?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function. You can make up your own like:

```
coolant_only = df['Type'].apply(lambda x: set(x)=={'Coolant'})

df[coolant_only]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what this function has done? there appears to be no option to search for 'Coolant'?

Comment: It worked! This is awesome. Thank you.
I tried doing df1[df1['Type' == 'SSPC']] but this throws an error. Could you explain why you'ved used curly brackets?

Comment: curly brackets denotes `set`, and `set(some_list)` removes duplicates in the list.